# ¿cómo valido que una lista de diccionarios contenga llaves específicas en python?

Tags: python, bucles, diccionarios, metodos

Qué tal, lo que quiero es que en una lista de diccionarios estén las llaves que yo diga, por ejemplo:

```
"list": [
    {
        "key1":"val1",
        "key2":"val2"
    },
    {
        "key1":"val1"
    }
]
```

esa lista puede contener n numero de diccionarios, pero en esos diccionarios deben estar las llaves "key1" y "key2" por lo que al hacer un método que lo valide, esa lista no es correcta, una correcta sería así:

```
"list": [
    {
        "key1":"val1",
        "key2":"val2"
    },
    {
        "key1":"val1",
        "key2":"val2"
    }
]
```

Yo estaba creando un método para eso pero no me funciona...

```
def chek_keys(array) ->bool:
    requ = True
    for i in array:
        if 'key1' not in i and 'key2' not in i:
            requ = False
            break
    return requ
```

Entiendo que i es el diccionario de la de cada posición, pero al preguntar si esas llaves están, no funciona, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Oliver. Tu función no se encuentra funcionando debido a que te encuentras comprobando si cada diccionario no contiene las claves `key1` **y** `key2`. Para corregir el error solo debes de cambiar el operador `and` por un `or`, de esta manera:

```
def chek_keys(array) ->bool:
    requ = True
    for i in array:
        if 'key1' not in i or 'key2' not in i: #Cambio realizado aquí
            requ = False
            break
    return requ
```

Así se encontraría comprobando si cada diccionario no contiene la clave `key1` **o** `key2`. Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y por la bienvenida, solucionaste mi problema, no puede ser que haya sido solo ese cambio... Muchas gracias!

Comment: @oliverQueen Consuelate: hay misiones espaciales que se ha perdido por errores como ese.

Answer (score 1):

Con una *expresión generadora*:

```
def check_array(lista):
    return all("key1" in dic and "key2" in dic for dic in lista)
```

Una expresión generadora es una expresión de lista que devuelve los elementos uno a uno en lugar de devolver la lista completa una vez formada.

La expresión examina uno a uno los diccionarios, comprobando que existan ambas llaves.

La función `all()` retorna `True` si todos sus argumentos lo son, y `False` en otro caso.